# Fallout shelter Broadcast Center

Tags: fallout-shelter

I noticed something a bit important with the Broadcast Center. When I first got it, I needed to wait about 2 hours before it would call a dweller. I have not seen any increment in this 2 hour time span, however I now need to wait 917 hours before it calls a dweller. Did they add a system to increase the time, or is this a glitch (If so, how would I fix it)?

Answer (score 4):

Did you change the date/time on your phone to mess with the game?  This is one of the buildings that will completely screw up if you change the date/time.  You might as well build a new one somewhere else first and trash this one.

Comment: Anecdotal advice: remove all dwellers, then re-assign new ones, that worked for me.

Comment: I didn't screw with the time and date, and I tried re-building it and re-assigning dwellers. Didn't work, so I gave up. Besides, the Deathclaws are getting to be too lethal. I can just use the old fashioned way to get more dwellers.

Comment: You actually can't rebuild at the same spot.  If you really want a radio room much later, build it at a different location.